# Ошибка с удалением элемента массива (C#)

Tags: c#, массивы

Задача: есть одномерный массив, размер которого n. Имеется число k, (1 < k < n). Нужно удалить элемент массива по индексу k.

Написал код, который, по идее, должен создавать копию этого массива без указанного элемента, но что-то пошло не так ;0

Ошибка:

```
Необработанное исключение: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Индекс находился вне границ массива.
```

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        link1:
        Console.Write("Введите значение n: ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Введите номер элемента k (1 < k < n ):  ");
        int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (true)
        {
            if (1 < k && k < n)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Ваше значение k не удовлетворяет необходимому условию.");
                Console.Write("Нажмите ENTER, дабы попробовать снова..");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                goto link1;
            }
        }

        int[] array = new int[n];
        int[] array_copy = new int[n - 1];

        for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            array_copy[i] = array[i];

            if (i == k) {
                continue;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Старый массив: " + array);
        Console.WriteLine("Новый массив: " + array_copy);
    }
```

Comment: "но что-то пошло не так" - а что именно, укажите в вопросе.

Comment: Внёс коррективы, спасибо.

Comment: Прикладывайте точное сообщение об ошибке, в нем почти все указано.

Comment: У вас массивы никак не заполняются, то есть они пустые. Если вам надо удалить элемент из пустого массива, то достаточно создать вройто массив размером на один элемент меньше. Нет нобходимости копировать данные из одного пустого массива в другой.

Comment: Условно, этот цикл заполнен какими-то данными.
Мне нужно было организовать сам механизм.

Comment: вам дали четыре ответа, пожалуйста примите один из них

Comment: Предлагаю вместо массива взять список `List<T>`. Он имеет встроенный метод `RemoveAt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У тебя `array_copy` длиной в `n-1`, а `for` происходит `n+1`(`<=`) раз (на 2 больше чем длина `array_copy` и на 1 больше `array`). Элементы по индексам `array_copy[n-1]`/`[n]` и `array[n]` не существуют, это и есть ошибка `IndexOutOfRange`.

Нумерация идет от 0 (`int i = 0`)! Если `n = 3`, то индексы 0, 1, 2.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i < k)
        array_copy[i] = array[i];
    else if (i > k)
        array_copy[i-1] = array[i];
}
```

Comment: Еще вот так можно `array_copy[i] = array[i < k ? i : i + 1]`

Comment: Да, тернарный оператор это классно, если хочешь взорвать `Jeffrey Willis` мозг, как в остальных ответах, в чём `tym32167` тебя переплюнул на 10 голов.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i0 = 0, i1 = 0; i0 < n; i0++, i1++)
        {
            if (i0 == k){i0++;)}
            array_copy[i1] = array[i0];
        }
```

В начале `i0` и `i1` идут параллельно, если `i0 == k` то `i0` увеличивается на один, и перепрыгиваеь через значение `array[k]`

Comment: Пожалуйста, можете объяснить, что вы сделали?

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    array_copy[i] = array[i];
```

Элементы массива в C# да и во многих других языках нумеруются с 0, соответственно первый элемент имеет индекс `0`, а последний - `n-1`. На последней же итерации цикла у вас `i` принимает значение `n` из-за условия `i <= n` и обращение к `array_copy[i]` и `array[i]` приводит к исключению.

Цикл должен быть до `i < n`. Но это не всё, вам нужно как-то отдельно проходить по индексу копии, потому что для неё и обращение к элементу `n-1` выдаст исключение.

Ответ Danis в принципе правильный после исправления правой границы цикла.

Comment: `array_copy[I]` отвалится и на предпоследней итерации.

Comment: @tym32167 Да, я дополнил уже. А потом ещё поправил

Answer (score 3):

ну тогда в копилку LINQ вариант

```
int[] array = new int[n];
int[] array_copy = array.Where((item, index)=>index != k).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё попробовать решить так:

```
var array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
for(int i = k; i < array1.Length - 1; i++)
{
    array1[i] = array1[i + 1];
}

Array.Resize(ref array1, array1.Length - 1);
```

Особого выйгрыша по памяти это не даст, потому что `Array.Resize()` всё равно создаёт новый массив и копирует в него все элементы оригинального, а потом заменяет оригинальный массив созданным, но может добавить читаемости коду.